# Set media left/right volume separately?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I would like to override the media left and right volume setting separately as a whole.

It does not seem possible to set the left and right volume separately using *AudioManager.setStreamVolume()*.
I noticed it is possible though to set it with *MediaPlayer.setVolume()* or *SoundPool.play()* but I would like to override the whole system media settings so the stereo balance would be kept among the different music players and applications.

I'm not really familiar with Android so I would welcome all advices, tips that could help me achieve this.

*ps: I am working on Android 2.3.4. and I would not mind if this needs to go through root rights.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Left / right volume adjustment for system / user is not available in the public API. It's only only available  on app level, using the methods you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the right and left volume with this 2nd and 3 parameter: 
[SoundPool, developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#play%28int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20float%29)

Comment: What I want to do is set the left/right balance on my app and then, what ever I use, Youtube, Google Music etc, the sound will be played with this same left/right balance. I don't think I can do this with SoundPool, right ?

Comment: No, the only thing you can control is the overall volume I think.