# Route audio through left and right speakers

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

I am looking to design and android app that would programmatically be able to route audio through the left and right speakers individually. That is when the song is played it would first route through the right speaker and it would then route it through the left speaker. The purpose of my app would be to validate that both the speakers are working fine. So far I haven't been able to successfully find any API that would do this .

Answer (score 5):

First, have you looked at other questions like [Set media left/right volume separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265933/set-media-left-right-volume-separatly). From that question I see that MediaPlayer.setVolume  lets you control left and right volume levels. See [MediaPlayer.SetVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume%28float,%20float%29).

Another thought would be to create two audio files with: one with only sound on the left channel, and one with only sound on the right channel, then your app can play one file then the other...

Comment: Thanks , I used the second approach where I took one sound from the left channel and the other one on the right channel. One other question , I obtained these tones from youtube. Is there a way for me to generate a tone that would play only on the left or right channel ?

Comment: Audacity (http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is one of the most popular and free tools for this type of editing. It can generate various tones. See http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Generate_Menu