# Is there a way to alter volume of left/right channels of audio output coming from android?

Tags: android, audio

I know that the AudioManager Class allows you to alter the stream volume coming from the device using the setStreamVolume function:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress , 0);
```

The problem is that it alters the volume coming from left/right channels together.

Are there any other libraries or ways to alter the volume coming from the left/right ears separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set media left/right volume separately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265933/set-media-left-right-volume-separately)